# Python - Error in thread when closing tkinter GUI window

Tags: python, tkinter

I am running a function that changes a label value in a thread while my tkinter is running. This code works unless I close the window before my thread stops. I have attached the error below.

How can I fix this problem? Is there a better way to set up these threads when using tkinter?

Code (works unless I close GUI window early):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import threading
import time

def fun():
    for i in range(10):
        var.set(var.get() + 1)
        print(var.get())
        time.sleep(.5)

t = threading.Thread(target=fun)

root = Tk()

var = IntVar()
var.set(0)

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root)
mainframe.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
label = ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=var)
label.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

t.start()
root.mainloop()
t.join()
print('Done')
```

Error when I close GUI window before `fun()` has finished running:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Done
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC-User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\PC-User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/PC-User/PycharmProjects/Arb/example.py", line 8, in fun
    var.set(var.get() + 1)
  File "C:\Users\PC-User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 503, in get
    value = self._tk.globalgetvar(self._name)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
```

Comment: As a general rule of thumb you should never call any tkinter functions (such as `var.get()` and `var.set()`) from any thread except the main thread. If the threads need to communicate, you need to set up a queue.

Comment: Cheers. How would I run this function 'fun()' from the main thread? When I use 'root.after(2000, fun)' before I call 'root.mainloop()' my GUI window does not run properly.

Comment: You shouldn't run it from the main loop if it's calling sleep, because that's exactly what will happen to your app - it will go to sleep.

Comment: That makes sense as to why I was I couldn't use the '.after'.

Comment: @BryanOakley If you know of any could you please refer me to somewhere that could help me implement queues to fix my code? I haven't been able to find anything yet.

Comment: I could show you how to make this specific code work, but that probably wouldn't help you make your real code work. Plus, you don't need threads if all you're doing is incrementing a variable. Threading with tkinter can be difficult, and it really depends on what you're needing to do in the other thread. There are already other questions and answers on this site related to writing threaded code, I doubt I could improve on them.

Comment: @BryanOakley I've been trying for a few days now. My 'fun()' I am working with is just receiving streaming data from a websocket connection and I just want to change the label when I receive new data. What would be the best method in this case? Thanks for your help btw.